# How to ignore "http://" and "www." when i search an url using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clean-urls, no-www

I have the following code in my urlSearch model:

```
def find_url(orig_url)
    url = find_by(url: orig_url)
    unless url
        # some stuff
    end
end
```

Here find_by will search for the exact string passed to it which is : `orig_url` argument in my case.

For example, if in my table i have an url like : `www.stackoverflow.com` and if i search for `http://stackoverflow.com` or `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, it's not the same string which means that `find_by` will return nil.

Is there is a way to tell `find_by` to ignore `http://` and `www.` when searching?

Comment: Ignore the input or the stored data ?

Comment: stored data, if for example in my database i have www.foobar.com and my search is "http://foobar.com", it will return a result

Answer (score 1):

You could do `url = find_by(url: orig_url.gsub("http://" , ""))`

And you'd need another gsub for `"www."`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a direct way to do this.  First, you have to extract the host from the string then remove `www` if it exists.

```
>> string = 'http://www.foobar.com'
>> host = URI.parse(string).host # www.foobar.com
>> host.gsub!(/^www\./, '') #foobar.com
>> MyModel.where('url LIKE ?', "%#{host}%").first
```

you should use `LIKE` (or `ILIKE` for postgresql) if you don't control the values stored in the database.  you can't use `find_by` in this case since that will always find an exact match.